# How to edit a gpx file in a spreadsheet and export the edited table to a new gpx?

Tags: gpx

I need to edit the date/time and the elevation of many trackpoints in a gpx file.
I tried to import the gpx file into an excel spreadsheet using the topografix xsd and the xml import command, but then I'm not able to export the table to a new xml file.

So what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how much data you have, it may we worth it to check out XML editors such as "XML Spy" or "Oxygen". They give you editing capabilities (some of them table-like, but I personally never use them because I prefer editing raw XML) that shield you from XML syntax. Transforming from/to XML would be tricky because GPX often contains data that cannot be easily mapped into a spreadsheet format, and you would lose all that data when doing the transformations.

Comment: Thank you @dret, I gave an eye on XMLSpy and I found that I can easily copy/paste attributes to/from Excel, so I can manipulate them in a spreadsheet applying any formula I need... just another question: do you know any XML free editor that offers this feature (the possibility to visualize attributes in a table and copy/paste them from/to it)?

Comment: it seems that a good XML editor is too hard to produce for any free one to be able to compete with the commercial ones. if you find a good one, please let us know, but i never found anything that came even close to the commercial ones.

Answer (score 1):

GPSBabel is like a swiss knife for GPS data conversion and processing. Syntax is a little bit strange and needs some trial and error. You can convert between gpx and several ASCII based formats back and forth. A build in function allows manipulation of height values.